# Tramp freezes Emacs with OpenSSH on Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, ssh

I just installed Emacs on my Windows machine for remote file editing using Tramp. However, I noticed than whenever I try to connect to a remote server (`C-x C-f /ssh:home:`), Tramp just displays `Opening connection for home using ssh... \` and completely hangs Emacs. I can't pull up the debug buffer with `(setq tramp-verbose 10)` since the entire application freezes.

I'm using [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) and the `ssh` and `scp` executables are both in my `PATH`.

My `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host home
        HostName xx.xx.xx.xx
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/home_rsa
        User nick
        Port xx
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect the remote server via ssh from whatever appears to be a command line on Windows?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus Yes, that works fine.

Comment: Hard to say then what happens. Do you see a chance to interrupt the hanging Emacs, in order to get the traces? Sending several `C-g` in a row?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus Unfortunately, no. Trying to get logs from `emacs --daemon` doesn't help either.

Comment: Well, in this case you must debug Tramp. A starting point would be `tramp-sh-file-name-handler`. If you need help, pls contact me via the Tramp mailing list `tramp-devel@gnu.org`, this kind of communication would exceed stackexchange rules.

Comment: Any advance on this issue?

Comment: @yorodm When we were communicating on the mailing list, I was pretty much told that I was out of luck and that I should just be using PuTTY instead of OpenSSH.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with plink :(

Comment: Found out that killing the ssh process under emacs at least fixes the freeze. Could not debug in any useful way, though. Previously I had issues with a login prompt not coming up, but not sure it's the same.